# How to use NSTextFinder with NSOutlineView?

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

There is not much information about how to use `NSTextFinder` and most of them are about `NSTextView`. I am interested to learn how to use it with `NSOutlineView`. This is what I have done.

On storyboard, I dragged an `NSTextFinder` onto a view controller where it contains an `NSOutlineView`. I connected the client to the view controller and the find bar container to the `NSScrollView` that encloses the `NSOutlineView`. I made an `@IBOutlet` to the `NSTextFinder` and enabled incremental searching and dim content view.

My code looks something like this.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var outlineView: NSOutlineView!
    @IBOutlet var textFinder: NSTextFinder!
    
    // ...
    
    @IBAction func findSomething(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("findSomething(_:) was called!")
        textFinder.performAction(.showFindInterface)
    }
}
```

I connected `findSomething(_:)` as a first responder to one of the `NSMenuItem`. The method is called and a find bar actually appear.

How do I actually get it to search strings in the `NSOutlineView`? I am not interested in find-and-replace. I just want it like Safari find bar.

Apple documentation on `NSTextFinder` is very hard to understand and there is no example code I could look into.

Comment: Maybe this helps [NSTextFinder Magic](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/01/12/nstextfinder-magic/).

Comment: That article is from 2012 and is most likely to be outdated. It is also written in Objective-C which I am not too familiar with and it is for `NSTableView`.

Comment: `NSTextFinder` probably didn't change much since 2012 and `NSOutlineView` is a subclass of `NSTableView`. The answer to "How do I actually get it to search strings" is "Implement the `NSTextFinderClient` protocol" but I think `NSTextFinder` with `NSOutlineView` will be very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

[willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke) is correct: Make your viewController, which owns the NSOutlineView, the client of the NSTextFinder and implement the [NSTextFinderClient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextfinderclient) protocol. For an outline view, you implement the methods `func stringLength() -> Int` and `func string(at: Int, effectiveRange: NSRangePointer, endsWithSearchBoundary: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> String` - you want to give the NSTextFinder the illusion that there's one giant string, broken into pieces.

Example when it asks for the piece that contains location 512, you return the string from 500 to 600, and store NSMakeRange(500, 100) into its effecive range argument.

When it actually finds something, it will call your `selectedRanges` setter for you to move the selection there.

To make this work. You'll need to do some work up front: to provide the illusion that your document is one giant range, you'll need to build a data structure that lets you map a range from NSTextFinder to a piece of your data.